# Scrapy wont print out to json, html or any other file

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to output my scraped elements to a json file. When I choose to print out the whole body of the page quotestoscrape.com it succesfully does so. But when I choose to print out certain elements like span tags or p tags, none of the scraped items shows up in the json file.
Here is my scrapy file, that TRIES to scrape the span.text elements from the site quotestoscrape.com:

```
import scrapy

class heyhey(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "samuelbb"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com"]
    def parse(self,response):
        with open("new.json","wb") as f:
            f.write(response.css("span::text").getall())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css is wrong

```
span::text
```

Use this cheat sheet to learn more [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

If you want to output in json

```
import scrapy

class heyhey(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "samuelbb"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com"]
    def parse(self,response):
        name = response.css("span::text").getall()
        yield{
            'name':name
        }
```

Command:

```
scrapy crawl samuelbb -o data.json
```

Comment: I just tried using :: instead, and it didnt make any difference.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to rewrite the whole code.